# Is there an option the the `find` command that filters results with an external command?

Tags: shell

Let's say I want to find all `.c` files in a given directory (and subdirectories) that contain a `main()`-function. The way I would do this is:

```
find . -name "*.c" -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' fl; do
    [ -r "$fl" ] && ctags -x --c-kinds=f "$fl" | grep -q "^main" && echo "$fl"
done
```

Here the magic is that `ctags -x --c-kinds=f myfile.c` parses `myfile.c` as the c-compiler would, and list all function definitions. It an output line starts with "main" (hence `grep -q "^main"`), there's a `main()`-function in `myfile.c`.

I thought there might be a way to tell `find` only to display results if `ctags -x --c-kinds=f "$fl" | grep -q "^main"` returns with `0` exit status. I find the whole loop and echo thing a bit hacky. Do you know of such an option?

Answer (score 2):

You could just do:

```
find . -name "*.c" -type f -exec \
  sh -c 'ctags -x --c-kinds=f "$1" | grep -q "^main" && echo "$1"' sh {} \;
```

It's probably more idiomatic to write:

```
find . -name "*.c" -type f -exec \
  sh -c 'ctags -x --c-kinds=f "$1" | grep -q "^main"' sh {} \; -print
```

Comment: I guess the second `sh` is just there so that the positional parameters start at `$1`? Also, maybe worth changing to `echo "$1"`.

Comment: Yeah, the "sh" becomes $0.  I go back and forth on whether or not to include it.  Stylistically, it seems weird to use $0 to be an argument.